# How to write noncapturing groups in egrep

Tags: grep

The following command does not correctly capture the `16714` from `16714 ssh -f -N -T -R3300:localhost:22`

```
egrep -o '^[^ ]+(?= .*[R]3300:localhost:22)'
```

(However swapping to grep does if you use the -P flag.  I was expecting egrep to be able to handle this)

Comment: I don't want the rest of the line, only the PID.  And the question is about egrep as I've obviously misunderstood what it's capable of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -P` forces grep to use the Perl regexp engine.
`egrep` is the same as `grep -E` and it forces grep to use the ERE (extended regular expression) engine, that does not support lookahead.
You can find a quick reference of the differences between Perl and ERE (and others) here : http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

To handle this with POSIX grep, you would use grep to isolate the lines of interest and then use `cut` to isolate the fields of interest:

```
$ echo "16714 ssh -f -N -T -R3300:localhost:22" | grep 'R3300:localhost:22' | cut -d' ' -f1
16714
```

Or, just use `awk`:

```
$ echo "16714 ssh -f -N -T -R3300:localhost:22" | awk '/R3300:localhost:22/{print $1}'
16714
```