# non matching groups in grep regex not working

Tags: regex, grep

I would like to extract 1, 10, and 100 from:

```
  1 one -args 123
 10 ten -args 123
100 one hundred -args 123
```

However this regex returns `100`:

```
echo -e "  1 one\n 10 ten\n100 one hundred" | grep -Po '^(?=[ ]*)\d+(?=.*)'
100
```

Not ignoring the preceding spaces returns the numbers (but of course with undesired spaces):

```
echo -e "  1 one\n 10 ten\n100 one hundred" | grep -Po '^[ ]*\d+(?=.*)'
  1
 10
100
```

Have I misunderstood non capturing regex groups in grep / Perl (grep version 2.2, Perl as the -P flag should use its regex) or is this a bug?  I notice the [release notes for 2.6 says "This release fixes an unexpectedly large number of flaws, from outright bugs (surprisingly many, considering this is "grep")"](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=6249).

If someone with 2.6 could try these examples that would be valuable to determine if this is a bug (in 2.2) or intended behaviour.

Comment: This doesn't directly address non-matching groups, but the regex `[0-9]*` does return 1, 10, 100, like you want

Comment: Thanks @daviscodesbugs, unfortunately these are (overly) simplified lines from `ps` output from which I want to extract PIDs from particularly processes with particular arguments (that contain numbers).  Thank you for your speedy response and kind suggestion though :)

Comment: As I side note I do not understand why Perl made positive and negative lookahead and lookbehind logic so complicated http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Ultimately I would say you are using the wrong tool, as awk could do this simply, but if you remove your anchor the data is returned.

Comment: Thanks @grail if you'd like to post an answer either with `grep -Po '(?=[ ]*)\d+(?=.*)'` or awk I'll make as correct, though it's still baffling that it matches `100` instead of all or nothing as it must be doing a multiline search.  Also would be good to include the explanation of awk being more suited than a regex if you have time.  Many thanks.

Comment: Please post a more realistic output then.

Comment: Done, thank you Jan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the unwanted spaces this way :

```
echo -e "  1 one\n 10 ten\n100 one hundred" | grep -Po '^[ ]*(\d+)' | tr -d ' '
```

As for your question of why it is not working, it is not a bug, it is working as intended, you just misinterpreted how it should work.

If we focus on this `^(?=[ ]*)\d+`:
The `(?=[ ]*)` part is a lookahead assertion. So it means that the regex engine tries to check if the `^` is followed by zero or more spaces. But the assertion itself is not part of the match, so in reality this code means :
 - Match a `^` that is followed by 0 or more spaces
 - After this `^`, match one or more digits

So your code will only match when a digit is the first character of the line. The lookahead won't help you on your use case.

Comment: Hey @CCH, thank you very much for a solution.  Do you know why grep is not working as intended.  Do you have v2.6+?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain why your code is working as expected. It is not a bug.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @CCH  That would also explain why adding a $ at the end results in no matches.  And that is also disappointing as Python, Javascript and Ruby have regexs that allow you to perform a non-capturing group match which is still used as part of the assertion.  One wonders why it was chosen that way in Perl as it seems to significantly limit its applications and therefore its usefulness, in fact I can't even imagine a use for "match, don't capture, forget you've matched entirely, then proceed to next part to match".

Comment: Oh and perhaps you might also be able to comment on this then?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468182

Comment: Yeah you normally wouldn't use a lookahead anywhere other than at the end of your match. In your case the more logical approach would have been to use a lookbehind, but lookbehind in grep can only be on a fixed-length string and you don't know how many spaces you can have here

Comment: But as a hack, you can try something like that using a lookbehind and grep only : `echo -e "  1 one\n 10 ten\n100 one hundred\n 200 e 233 e 555\n    400" | grep -Po '(?<=^|^ |  |   |     )\d+'`. It only works if you don't have more than 4 leading spaces though, otherwise you would have to add more pipes and spaces :)

Comment: @CCH: `echo -e " 1 one\n 10 ten\n100 one hundred\n 200 e 233 e 555\n 400" | grep -Po '[ ]+\K\d+'` handles an unlimited amount of leading spaces and is easier to understand.

Comment: If you want just the first column of numbers: `echo -e " 1 one\n 10 ten\n100 one hundred\n 200 e 233 e 555\n 400" | grep -Po '^[ ]*\K\d+'`

Comment: @dawg You're right your way is more elegant, but \K is not available on version 2.2 of grep (which the OP is using).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is what is considered a 'match' by grep. In the absence of telling grep part of the total match is not what you want, it prints everything up to the end of the match regardless of matching groups.

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
  1 one -args 123
 10 ten -args 123
100 one hundred -args 123
```

You can get just the first column of digits without leading spaces several ways.

With GNU grep:

```
$ echo "$txt" | grep -Po '^[ ]*\K\d+' 
1
10
100
```

Here `\K` is equivalent to a look behind assertion that resets the match text of the match to be what comes after. The left hand, before the `\K`, is required to match, but is not included in match text printed by grep.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ppM1KG/1)

awk:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk '/^[ ]*[0-9]+/{print $1}'
```

sed:

```
$ echo "$txt" | sed 's/^[ ]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

Perl:

```
$ echo "$txt" | perl -lne 'print $1 if /^[ ]*\K(\d+)/'
```

And then if you want the matches on a single line, run through `xargs`:

```
$ echo "$txt" | grep -Po '^[ ]*\K(\d+)' | xargs
1 10 100
```

Or, if you are using awk or Perl, just change the way it is printed to not include a carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

I think the anchor messes with the lookahead, which could be a lookbehind, but they can't be ambiguous (I always run into that one).  So the following would work:

```
echo -e "  1 one\n 10 ten\n100 one hundred" | grep -Po '(?=[ ]*)\d+(?=.*)'
```

As for a better tool, I would use awk as it is suited to any column driven data.  So if you were running it off of ps you could do something like:

```
ps | awk '/stuff you want to look for here/{print $1}'
```

awk will take care of all the white space by default

Comment: This won't work if there are digits anywhere else than at the beginning of the line, as the OP says :     `unfortunately these are (overly) simplified lines from ps output from which I want to extract PIDs from particularly processes with particular arguments (that contain numbers)`

Comment: @grail, thanks for the answer.  Apologies for changing the goal posts.  And thank you very much for the explanation of situations to use awk and grep.